# What is the purpose of the Hibernate ReturningWork<Long> interface?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, orm

I am working on one JAVA + Hibernate project but currently, I saw one interface in my code (i.e. `ReturningWork<Long>`) which has one method called `execute(java.sql.Connection)`.

My question is what is the use of this `ReturningWork` interface?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I explained in more details [on my blog](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-get-the-sql-connection-used-by-your-hibernate-session/), you can use the `ReturningWork` and the Work interfaces to implement any logic that requires direct access to the `java.sql.Connection` used by your Hibernate session.

Here is a simple example that uses the `ReturningWork` interface to execute a very simple query (which you could also implement with [JPQL](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpql/)) and return the result.

```
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
Integer bookCount = session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Integer>() {

    @Override
    public Integer execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        // do something useful
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT count(b.id) FROM Book b")) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            return rs.getInt(1);
        }
    }
});

log.info("Found " + bookCount + " books.");
```

Comment: And do not forget to close your ResultSet, as it will cause a memory leak :)

Comment: My question is what happens when you want the connection "free", and you achieve that by returning the connection passed from doReturningWork ... would that not essentially be the same as getConnection() ?

Answer (score 12):

### Hibernate Session Hibernate `Session` `doReturningWork`

The Hibernate `Session` [`doReturningWork`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#doReturningWork-org.hibernate.jdbc.ReturningWork-) method has the following signature:

```
<T> T doReturningWork(ReturningWork<T> work) throws HibernateException;
```

And the `ReturningWork` interface looks as follows:

```
public interface ReturningWork<T> {
    public T execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException;
}
```

So, unlike the `doWork` method, the `doReturningWork` allows us to return an object to the method caller.

For example, we can use the `doReturningWork` method to get the current transaction isolation level:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

int isolationLevel = session.doReturningWork(
    connection -> connection.getTransactionIsolation()
);

assertEquals(
    Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED, 
    isolationLevel
);
```

### When to use `doWork` and `doReturningWork`?

In general, you can use the JPA or Hibernate-specific API to execute SQL statements or call database procedures or functions.

However, if you want to get access to the underlying JDBC `Connection` method and execute any possible operation via the JDBC API, then you need to use the `doWork` and `doReturningWork` Hibernate `Session` methods.

Comment: my question is what happens when you want the connection "free", and you achieve that by returning the connection passed from doReturningWork ... would that not essentially be the same as getConnection() ?

Comment: @mjs I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about.